# Next.js deployment change the font size

Tags: javascript, css, heroku, next.js, font-size

I deploy my next.js but the font size will get change and the looks is totally different than the looks in local. Here is the link that I deployed https://yasamanforouzesh.herokuapp.com/contact and here is my Github https://github.com/YasamanForouzesh/yasamanforouzeshportfolio
[image: This is the view from the local]

[image: This is the view of my app when I deploy it.]

Comment: Your live website looks similar to what you have on localhost to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was zoom in. If you look at my local app, you can see magnifier at the top that my deploy app doesn't have so I zoom out in local and both got the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please increase the **magnification level** of the magnifier on Google's search bar to **100%**. Currently, it appears to be set at 90% when accessed locally.